# Disable Laravel Slack Logging When Configured URL Is Null

Tags: php, laravel, logging, slack

Here's the configuration for my Slack logging channel:

```php
        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'critical'),
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ],
```

When `LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL` is not set in the `.env`, I would like the channel to not be used. How do I accomplish that?

Currently if I leave `LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL` unset, I get this exception:

> TypeError: Monolog\Handler\SlackWebhookHandler::__construct(): Argument #1 ($webhookUrl) must be of type string, null given, called in...

Comment: Why not just use a `LOG_CHANNEL` that doesn't include this driver in these scenarios?

Comment: @TimLewis If you make that an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to use multiple logging channels (single file, daily file, slack notifications, etc.) in a Laravel Application, you use the `stack` driver:

In `config/logging.php`:

```php
<?php

return [
  'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
  // ...
  'stack' => [
    'driver' => 'stack',
    'channels' => ['single'],
    'ignore_exceptions' => false
  ],
];
```

By default, only a single channel is provided. If you want to use multiple channels based on a condition, you can use an in-line ternary:

```php
'channels' => ['single', env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL') ? 'slack' : null],
// OR
'channels' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL') ? ['single', 'slack'] : ['single'],
```

In this situation, the `slack` channel will only be included if the `LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL` is set in your `.env` file, otherwise only the `single` channel (single `laravel.log` file) will be used.